# Debug java code in Eclipse IDE using Ant script

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, ant

How can I debug web application developed in eclipse using ant script fro build and deploy. Is there something I have to include in build.xml or there is any setting in eclipse. I am new to Ant script. Please help......

Comment: You develop your web app in Eclipse, build and deploy it with Ant. One way to debug your code is to start the web app server in debug mode (e.g. tomcat in Windows: `catalina.bat jdpa run`), and remote debug it with your Eclipse. Nothing you need to change in Ant.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [remote debugging](http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html) for the webapp, don't need to change the Ant script.